# How to rename element in object

Tags: javascript, object

I have obejct data like this :

`{radiant: 11, dire: 22}`

and I want to change it like this :

`{aplha: 11, omega: 22}`

how to do that?

Comment: 1. add a new property with different name 2. delete the old property.

Comment: I would create a function for that:
```
const obj = {radiant: 11, dire: 22};

const renameKey = (object, key, newKey) => {
    const clonedObj = object;
    const targetKey = clonedObj[key];
    delete clonedObj[key];
    clonedObj[newKey] = targetKey;
    return clonedObj;
};

renameKey(obj, 'radiant', 'alpha');
renameKey(obj, 'dire', 'omega');

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: @OlivierGirardot I wouldn't use that function. It's not much of an improvement over doing it in two lines. Also, it's creating `clonedObj` which is in no way shape or form a cloned object but literally *the same* reference as the one passed in, so calling the function will always mutate the input.

Comment: True. The function is only useful if he wants to perform that operation agin in the futur for other objects, I guess.
Yes you are right it is not a cloned object, I should have named it differently. Thanks!